# is there a way to call a tkinter button if you don't assign a variable to it?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root = Tk()

def select(n):
    lst.append(n)

for i in range(4):
    Button(root, text="button"+str(i), command=lambda x="button"+str(i): select(x,x)).grid(row=0, column=i)

root.mainloop()
```

is there a way where I can call this button to re-configure?

Comment: There is probably a way to scan the widget tree, but why not just save references in a list or dictionary?

Comment: Save the button in a list or dictionary.

Comment: @BryanOakley how so?

Comment: @RufusVS what references exactly?

Comment: How so? `buttons = []; ... buttons.append(Button(root, ...))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't think I understand what you mean by "call a button". In programming, you call *functions*. Perhaps you meant "refer to"? But I don't like guessing things. I also don't understand what you mean by "this" button, because it seems that you intend to create four buttons. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: "how [do I save the buttons into a list]?" The same way that you are currently attempting to save strings into the `lst` list via your callback: by creating a list, and then writing code that puts things into it, for example using `.append`. In this case, the things you put in are the `Button` instances. I don't understand what needs explaining.

Comment: @KarlKnechte If you want to name your buttons after declaring them then use     `button = list(root.children.keys())` to give you a list of all buttons by names. These can be used to access `root.children` values, which are the actual button widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all widgets using `root.children`, this will return a dictionary of all widgets as keys and a reference to those widgets as values.

Here is a demonstration that changes your coded button background colors to red and displays `widget.keys()` data in shell.

"""

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

for i in range(4):
    tk.Button(root, text = f"button{i}").grid(row = 0, column = i, sticky = tk.NS)

# collect all objects
buttons = root.children
for k, v in buttons.items():
    print(k, v.keys())

    # Arbitrarily change colors
    buttons[k]['background'] = "red"
    # Change text in buttons
    buttons[k]['text'] = "New name"
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there a way to get the text of the button and the k value and make a key-value pair so that I can use them later?

Comment: Yes, `widget.keys()` will display all available widget attributes including `text`. I'll modify my answer to include that change.